# How to fix "Connection to Redis failed" error?

Tags: magento2.2.6, redis, local

I cannot open the site and can't run any commands. I'm getting the below error:

[image]

The thing is that I have configured our development site into local (Xampp). In the development site, we have used the redis cache. I think this is the reason why the error is throwing.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Make sure you can connect to redis on the command line first before adding it to your store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be temporary solution,

just give it try remove redis configuration from the development server

> Go to app/etc/env.php

remove or command the redis configuration and run the command.

Hope this helps

Comment: I have tried this on local and it's work fine. Thanks you

Answer (score 2):

Remove below code from app/etc/env.php

```
  'cache' => [
           'frontend' => [
            'default' => [
                'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
                'backend_options' => [
                    'server' => 'redis',
                    'database' => '0',
                    'port' => 'XXXX'
                ]
            ],
            'page_cache' => [
                'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
                'backend_options' => [
                    'server' => 'redis',
                    'port' => 'XXXX',
                    'database' => '1',
                    'compress_data' => '0'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
```